# How can I encrypt a file on Windows 8 before storing it on Dropbox?

Tags: encryption, dropbox, cloud, cloud-storage

I would like to store some sensitive information in the cloud (my preferred cloud service is Dropbox).  I would like to encrypt it before putting it in the Dropbox folder for synchronization.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I would be interested to see what solution you picked.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some options:

- [Secretsync](http://getsecretsync.com/ss/)

Free for the first 2GB, $40/yr for < 20GB, $60/yr < 1TB. Java app, runs on Windows, Linux, Mac. Any files in a designated folder get encrypted.

- [AES Crypt](http://www.aescrypt.com/)

Opensource & free to use. Provides single file encryption. Works on Windows, Linux, Mac.

- [Cloudfogger](http://www.cloudfogger.com/en/)

Free to use for non-commercial use. Runs on Windows, Mac. Encrypts entire Dropbox folder, and other designated folders. Licensing states that the free version available now will always bee free.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the size you could create a [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) container. Obviously if it is a 5GB container you might not want to use it, but for small files it could work. You'd just have to mount the drive before copying files.

Answer (score 2):

You could try secret sync. Seems like a simple way to auto encrypt files before adding them to DropBox. http://getsecretsync.com/ss/

Comment: This option is free for the first 2GB, $40/yr for < 20GB, $60/yr < 1TB.

Answer (score 1):

I use TrueCrypt with DropBox myself. This combination was previously considered: [Security Considerations when Storing Documents with TrueCrypt in Dropbox](https://superuser.com/questions/304415/security-considerations-when-storing-documents-with-truecrypt-in-dropbox)

A relatively small encrypted container (~100MB) is more than enough for a lot of text-based sensitive data. You could also experiment with a dynamic sizing container. I went with that, but I got the feeling that the allocated space was using up some of my DropBox quota. I'll have to investigate more to see whether the dynamic bit actually ended up saving me anything.

One other consideration (and something else you've inspired me to test): you probably can't have the same container open on two computers at once. Or rather, if you do, you'll probably end up with a conflict and the entire container will be duplicated on DropBox.

Answer (score 0):

To add another option, I use [Boxcryptor Classic](https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/classic) which provides a mounted virtual drive to access the plaintext files, but the encrypted files are stored on a one-to-one basis (which I believe distinguishes it from other providers). So each (virtual) plaintext file is backed by one encrypted file in dropbox. This makes it very efficient for Dropbox to sync the encrypted files. It is based on EncFS and has clients available for most platforms.